# Error when parsing through items in list and finding product Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python, list, numpy, int

So I'm trying to make a program to find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. This is a problem for the Euler project and i keep running into error message:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

here is the code though i shortend the 1000 digit number down for this post:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
allDigits = 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395783180169848018694788518438586156078911294949545950173795833195285320880551112540698747158

d = [int(d) for d in str(allDigits)]

digits = d[:13]

products = []

del d[:13]


while len(d) > 0:

    tempProd = 1

    for i in digits:

        tempProd *= i

    products.append(tempProd)

    nextDigit = d[:1]

    del digits[:1]
    digits.append(nextDigit)

    del d[:1]

products.sort()

print(products)
```

I am running into the problem in the line where it says:

```
tempProd *= i
```

This is really confusing me as neither of the values should be a list, i have tried using the numpy product function aswell as creating my own function which runs into the same problem and looks like this:

```
def prod(x):
    return reduce(operator.mul, int(x), 1)
```

Any help would be much apreciated you can find more information about the problem im trying to solve here:
https://projecteuler.net/problem=8

Comment: "neither of the values should be a list"?  *should be*?  Why don't you know yet?  This is a simple print statement, one of the most basic debugging tools.  Print them out and *see* what you have.  The run-time system is the highest authority you can ask!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
nextDigit = d[:1] # returns a list
digits.append(nextDigit)
```

d[:1] returns a list which is then appended to the digits list so when you read it in the for loop you are multiplying i by a list value.

One way to fix this is to simply just do

```
nextDigit = d[:1][0]
```